# Error when installing Makefile: "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Tags: makefile

In short while I run the `make` command it says:

```
nir@nir:~/Downloads/xf86-video-intel-2.17.0$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I looked inside the folder-xf86-video-intel-2.17.0 and there is a file named "Makefile.in"
it supposed to be a in file, right?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That happens because there is no file named **Makefile** in that directory. To create that Makefile, you need to execute

```
$ ./configure
```

The *configure* script determines if your system has all the dependencies necessary to compile the application. If a dependency is not found, the *configure* will fail and the Makefile's will not be created. To solve that, you must install all the dependencies needed by the application.

The application xf86-video-intel seems to be provided by the xserver-xorg-video-intel package, and its dependencies may be easily installed by running

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

For more information, you might want to read the README or INSTALL files.

Comment: should i install also new kernal? don't i have already the kernal i need with normal updaet? I heve now the 3.0.0-15 version. intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q4.html install it like every makefile?

Answer (score 5):

Just remember that in order for the `./configure` file to run you made need a compiler.  So do something like `sudo apt-get install gcc`.  then run `./configure` again and should work

Comment: I have a `Makefile.am` and a `Makefile.in` but no `Makefile`

Comment: Took me quite some time to realize `Makefile` _is_ the file type, without a file extension. Useful comment.

Answer (score 3):

The make command looks for a file called "Makefile", no extension, not "Makefile.in". Since the file is not found, make does not know what to do, and stops. (The error message is cryptic because in some rare cases, make can guess what to do without an actual Makefile.)

Read the instructions on how to compile your program. It's likely that you are required to run `./configure`, first. This script will create "Makefile" based on your setup and "Makefile.in".

You can temporarily disable the Hebrew locale when looking for help online, just run

```
LC_ALL=C make
```

This will give you English messages.

Comment: More precisely, `autoreconf` generated Makefile.in from Makefile.am and `configure` creates `Makefile` from it.

Comment: should i install also new kernal? don't i have already the kernal i need with normal updaet?                                              I heve now the 3.0.0-15 version.                                   http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q4.html                             install it like every makefile?

Comment: should i install it by the order?

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry..
There are only some packages need to be intalled..
type "sudo synaptic" in terminal and enter..
in search box type "qt4-qmake" and mark for installation.
then same as above search" libqt4-dev" and "libxml2-dev" and do the same mark for installation simultaneously..
then apply without check the download option.
here it is....
Then go to cd netanim directory and type "make clean" and enter, 
if it does not work type "qmake NetAnim.pro" and enter, it takes couple of seconds.
then type "make" and enter...
Here its done, it will take less then a minute.
 Now in netanim directory type "./NetAnim" and enter.

Here you will see animation interface.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed this file or

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

Now, you need to configure the installation file

```
./configure
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install the Required Dependencies

First, launch the Terminal and run the commands below to install the required dependencies and libraries.

`sudo apt install autoconf automake libpcre3-dev libnl-3-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev ethtool build-essential g++ libnl-genl-3-dev libgcrypt20-dev libtool python3-distutils`

`sudo apt install -y pkg-config`

Step 2: Compile and Install

Now, run the commands below (one by one in order) to compile the source code and install Your Repo on your system.
[Before this enter you directory ex: cd folder_name]

`sudo autoreconf -i`

`sudo ./configure --with-experimental --with-ext-scripts`

`sudo make`

`sudo make install`

I hope this time problem will be solved.