# sudo make won't work

Tags: installation, 13.10, software-installation, tar

I can't install anything in `.tar.gz` format because it tells me `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` What do I do?

Comment: `.tar.gz` files are just compressed archives (tar stands for TapeARchive and gz stands for GZipped) You will have to extract the contents to a folder, typically something like `tar xvzf filename.tar.gz` Then `cd` to the folder (it will include any necessary `.make` files) and run any necessary commands to build the software and install it. Typically `./configure` `make` and `make install` (this last one may require `sudo` appended to it. Consult the `readme` files usually included in the archive.

Comment: I've done that. It says `no makefile found`

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What files were extracted? What is the full name of the .tar.gz? Where did it come from?

Comment: .tar.gz file; p7zip_9.20.1~dfsg.1.orig.tar.gz
output

Comment: If there is no `.make` file then perhaps there's a binary installer or shell script (`.sh`). Ordinarily there should be a `install` or `readme` text file with instructions on how to procceed.

Comment: You might go to [http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/9.20.1/] and download `p7zip_9.20.1_src_all.tar.bz2` That contains the source that you could compile with `make`  You could also download the binaries for linux.

Comment: i found the make files for p7zip, do they not appear if you dont extract from the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing Makefile: "make: \*\*\* No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103348/error-when-installing-makefile-make-no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something you are missing ... either name not correctly spelled ... i will refer you to this

[Error when installing Makefile: "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103348/error-when-installing-makefile-make-no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile)

Comment: `No such file or directory`